# How to debug the DataSnapshot snapshot using println in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

From a newb, I found no clear answer.

**UPDATED**

I tried a Boolean (nameExists) to see if a userName exists in the FirebaseDb, so I do...

```
  public void addNameToFirebase() {
   ... gets name from editText

    Firebase mCheckForNameRef = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL_BMN);
    mCheckForNameRef.child(grabbedname).child(grabbedname).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean nameExists = (Boolean) snapshot.getValue();

            if (!nameExists) {   // Does not exist yet - So create

                System.out.println(snapshot.child("name").getValue());
                // Want too see whats going on in system.out printLn - how?

                UserName msg = new UserName();
                msg.setDate(new Date());
                msg.setText(grabbedname);
                msg.setmPoints(505);
                msg.setmCounter(1);
                Utils.saveUserName(msg, mConvoId, listId);


            } else {   // Already exists - So Update

            System.out.println(snapshot.child("name").getValue());
            // Want too see whats going on in system.out printLn- how?

                Counter nameCount = new Counter();
                nameCount.setDate(new Date());
                nameCount.setText(grabbedname);
                msg.setmPoints(0);
                nameCount.setmCounter(3);
                nameCount.setmGender(Integer.valueOf(currentGender));
                Utils.updateUserName(nameCount, mConvoId, listId);


            }
        }
        @Override
     ...
    });

}
```

What could be causing this behavior? It creates newUser then when the same name is selected it should do 2nd block.

I should also add that I've enabled disk persistence if that's any clue.

Comment: Can you post an example that demonstrates this phenomenom?  IE: an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added the MCVE as requested.